# Find & replace data in a CSV using Python on Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I'm new to python, zapier and pretty much everything, so forgive me if this is easy or impossible...

I'm trying to import multiple csv's into zapier for an automated workflow, however they contain dot points that aren't formatted using UTF-8, which is all zapier can read.

It consistently errors -
"utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 829: invalid start byte"

After talking to zapier support, they've suggested using python to possibly find an replace these dot points with asterisk or dash, then import this corrected csv into my zapier workflow.

This is what i have written so far as a Python action in Zapier (just trying to read the csv to start with) with no luck:

```
import csv 
with open(input_data['file'], 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader:
print(row)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

[Zapier trying to import CSV with bullet points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrdWI.png)

[My current python code (not working) in an attempt to find & replace bullet points in the CSV's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykdZ4.png)

Comment: why use python? If you have only one CSV, just replace the characters directly. A csv file is a text file, open it with any text editor and Ctrl+H to replace the character that is the problem. Yes you can do it with python but it will be more complex as you need to load the file, use the replace function on a string and save the file after. It's not complicated but feels unnecessary.

Comment: add the code you have tried and also include the complete error in the post

Comment: I'm trying to automate a workflow which could be up to 10 CSV's per day, otherwise I would just manually edit them. I will include my code so far and the indicated errors!

Comment: I have edited my post to show pictures of the error's, with my current python attempt (no find& replace yet, just trying to open the csv so far). Thanks!

Comment: Please show code and errors as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it's a little tricky. Zapier is confusing when it comes to files. On your computer, files are a series of bytes. But in Zapier, a file is usually a url that points to the actual file. This is great for cross-app compatibility, but tricky to work with in code.

You're trying to open to open a url as a file in Python, which isn't working. Instead, make a request for that file, then read it as a series of bytes. Try this:

```py
import csv
import io

file_data = requests.get(input_data['file'])
reader = csv.reader(file_data.content.decode('utf-8').splitlines(), delimiter=',')

result = io.StringIO() # a string interface to write
writer = csv.writer(result)
for row in reader:
    # some modifications here
    # row = row.replace(...)
    writer.writerow(row)

return [{'data': result.getvalue()}]
```

The `result` there is because you want to write *out* a string that you can then re-package as a CSV in your virtual filesystem of choice (gDrive, Dropbox, etc).

---

You can also test this locally instead of in the Zapier editor (I find that's a bit easier to iterate with). Simply get the file url from the code step (it'll be something like `https://zapier.com/engine/...` and make a local python file with:

```py
input_data = {'file': 'https://zapier.com/engine/...'}

...
```

You'll also need to `pip install requests` if you don't have it.

Comment: Fantastic! This works, although I just had to change the decode('utf-8') to decode('latin1'). The only issue now is the it has broken up the formatting and line-items are now getting mixed up/not consistent, so e.g. line-item 16 is sometimes email or due date or products etc. I will have a play around and see what I can do. If you have any further ideas feel free to add! Thanks very much.

Comment: I guess one more question if I'm allowed to ask, the output of this has been stripped of rows, it is now just one big string of text with commas in between making it pretty tricky to format. Is there any way of keeping line-items/rows? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your input is like, so it's hard to know how to answer. When you do a `writerow`, it _should_ add a newline so that the resulting string is itself a valid csv file. If you're still having trouble, you can always post a new question with information about the new problem

Comment: In any case, if this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).